# Why does setting Product2 field on OrderItem allow you to see Product2 fields in Apex/Visualforce and only using Product2Id does not?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Using the below function for example to set an OrderItemList and then referencing that through visualforce with `<apex:outputField value="{!o.Product2.Family}" />` only works with  `oi.Product2 = pbe.Product2;`. 
If I remove that line it won't show.

```
List<OrderItem> oiList = new List<OrderItem>();
for (PricebookEntry pbe : List<PricebookEntry>)standardSetController.getRecords()) {
                OrderItem oi = new OrderItem();
                oi.UnitPrice = pbe.UnitPrice;
                oi.PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id;
                oi.Product2Id = pbe.Product2Id;
                oi.Quantity = 0;
                oi.Product2 = pbe.Product2;
                oiList.add(oi);
                system.debug('orderExtension - getOrderItemList - oi = ' + oi);
            }
```

Surely having the ID should be enough to traverse through the related object, but clearly not the case.

I don't understand how this works.

Does this work for other objects or just junction objects like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, **if you assign the Id, you can access the Id, but in order to access all the rest of the fields, you would have to assign them too**. Think of SOQL - when you try to access a field/property you have not queried it throws an exception saying: `System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Some_Field__c`.

Therefore, I would assume the overall language/framework works in the same way: in order to access field values you need to have queried them or at least assigned them.

In any case, it does make sense - in any other language you do not have the data until you have it, that is, a variable won't have a value until you assign it to it.

Furthermore, if you do execute the line `i.Product2 = pbe.Product2` but `pbe.Product2` only has the Id, I would assume you would still not be able to access any of the other fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Javier. 
pbe.Product2 is assigned, pbe.Product2Id is however.
I used the following query : [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Family, Product2.Name, Product2.Quantity_Remaining__c, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE IsActive = true]

It may be that since I queried fields on product2 from pbe, Product2.Name  for instance, that in itself has created an instance of the Product2 object related to pbe.

Comment: 'if you assign the Id, you can access the Id, but in order to access all the rest of the fields, you would have to assign them too.' I'm assuming that oi.Product2 = pbe.Product2 in this case assigns all the available (queried) fields to oi automatically.

This makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @rna7 I'm glad it helped! If that solved your question, don't forget to mark it as answered :)